# create a rails dropdown search by category

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a auction model and a category model.
Auction belongs_to category and category has_many auctions
How can i build a dropdown search by category in first page for auctions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your views

```
<%= select_tag "category_id", options_from_collection_for_select(Category.all, "id", "name") %>
```

By default you can display all the auction no matter with category
On change of category form will submit based on category_id you can fetch the auctions

For Basic search you can refer [railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/37-simple-search-form)

Comment: This gives me a dropdown selector in my view but how can i give it a method to render the auctions of the specific category?

Comment: Might be you want similar http://dmr.heroku.com/ source is https://github.com/amardaxini/dynamic_report

Comment: Thank you!this work for me!But i have one more question,when i select a category and gives me the auctions the cartegory selector returns to the first selection.How can i prevent this and keeps the category that i have select?

Comment: Try this <%= select_tag "category_id", options_from_collection_for_select(Category.all, "id", "name",params[:category_id]) %>